# Ошибка "ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum" в циклах

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Исходные данные:

```
Data    GVKey   x   x2
1982    1013    -0,034482437    -0,06054818
1982    1013    0,214285714 -0,010167112
1982    1013    0,058823529 0,040014318
2011    1177    0,098238855 -0,005058715
2011    1177    0,051810865 0,008532764
2011    1177    0,008847441 0,043583062
```

Есть такой код:

```
a=df1.GVKey
b=set(a)
b=list(b)
range = b
a1=df1.Data
b1=set(a1)
b1=list(b1)
range1 = b1
lst1 = []
lst2 = []
lst3 = []
for i in range:
    df2=df1[df1['GVKey']==i]
    for r in range1:
        df3=df2[df2['Data']==r]    
    x= df2['x2']
    y = df2['x']
    smm = sm.OLS.from_formula('x2 ~ x', data=df3)
    res = smm.fit()
    res.params
    df5 = res.params
    b = df5['x']
    lst1.append(i)
    lst2.append(r)
    lst3.append(b)
    #Создаем DF с двумя колонками куда вписываются значения двух списков
itog = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([lst1, lst2, lst3]), 
                           columns=['FIRM','Data' 'BETA'])`
```

Ошибка в том, что для некоторых GVKey нет годов из Data, поэтому выдает ошибку: `zero-size array to reduction operation maximum` Подскажите, как это решить?
Программа начнет искать для `1013` искать 2011 год, и получит пустой DF и не сможет построить регрессию. 
Как я понял, нужно поставить внутри цикла условие, что если года нет такого, то пропустить просто.

То есть на выходе нужно получить:

`FIRM   Data    BETA
1013    1982    0,148
1177    2011    -0,54` , где х - рассчитанный параметр из регрессии

Comment: можете привести в вопросе воспроизводимый пример данных?

Comment: Может цикл не до конца верный, нужно чтобы он брал каждую компанию (GVKey), и каждый год и выводил параметр из регрессии

Comment: Можете привести в вопросе пример выходных данных? Вы пытаетесь найти коэффициенты для линейной регрессии для каждой фирмы?

Comment: Да, коэффициент бетта , сейчас допишу что должно получиться там. Добавил!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Векторизированное (без циклов) решение:

```
from statsmodels.regression.linear_model import OLS

res = (df.groupby(['GVKey','Data'])[['x','x2']]
         .apply(lambda g: OLS.from_formula('x2 ~ x', g)
                             .fit()
                             .params['x'])
         .reset_index(name='Beta'))
```

результат:

```
In [124]: res
Out[124]:
   GVKey  Data      Beta
0   1013  1982  0.148955
1   1177  2011 -0.540772
```

---

Коэффициенты возвращаемые `OLS`:

```
In [116]: OLS.from_formula('x2 ~ x', df1[df1['GVKey']==1177]).fit().params
Out[116]:
Intercept    0.044328
x           -0.540772
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо . А если бы я захотел другой параметр из регрессии вытащить, что нужно было написать в `params['']` ?

Comment: OLS после обучения возвращает два параметра `x` и `Intercept`, что соответствует формуле: `f(Z) = Z*x + Intercept`, где `Z` - переменная, а `x` - значение коэффициента

Comment: @Max52, Т.е. в решении надо было бы использовать `params['Intercept']` вместо `params['x']`

Comment: Нет, у вас все верно

Comment: @Max52, это был ответ на ваш вопрос: `А если бы я захотел другой параметр из регрессии вытащить, что нужно было написать в params[''] ?` ;-)

Comment: Понял, благодарю